# API do Facebook - Extrair URL da foto de capa de fan page do facebook

Tags: php, facebook

Boa tarde.

Estou começando a estudar a API do facebook e estou com dificuldade em pegar a URL da foto de capa de alguma fan page.

Não estou conseguindo montar o get para me trazer a informação desejada.

Conforme código abaixo já gerei o token para acesso a API e está acessando normal.

Preciso de ajuda na request. Seguinte trecho de código $request = $fb->request('GET', '/'.$page_id.'/)

Alguém com mais experiência na API pode me ajudar.

```
include 'vendor/autoload.php';

$page_id = '1634111220214490';
$app_id = ''; //Preenchi este valor
$app_secret = ''; //Preenchi este valor

$fb = new \Facebook\Facebook([
 'app_id' => $app_id
 ,'app_secret' => $app_secret
]);

$expires = time()+(60*60)*2; //Auxilia na geração do token

$fbAt = new \Facebook\Authentication\AccessToken($app_id.'|'.$app_secret, $expires);
$token = (string)$fbAt;

$fb->setDefaultAccessToken($token);

//O erro está nesta linha
$request = $fb->request('GET', '/'.$page_id.'/);

$response = $fb->getClient()->sendRequest($request);

$body = $response->getBody();

$obj = json_decode($body);

var_dump($obj);
```

Answer (score -1):

O erro é na barra da direita eu ACHO. Tire ela.. ou adicione algum nome de campo depois dela .. 
Tipo
 '/'.$page_id.'/cover'